# For each word in the text file, extract surrounding 5 words

Tags: python, python-3.x

For each occurrence of a certain word, I need to display the context by showing about 5 words preceding and following the occurrence of the word.

Example output for the word 'stranger' in a text file of content when you enter `occurs('stranger', 'movie.txt')`:

My code so far:

```
def occurs(word, filename):

    infile = open(filename,'r')
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    infile.close()

    wordsString = ''.join(lines)
    words = wordsString.split()
    print(words)

    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i].find(word):
            #stuck here
```

Comment: Print the preceeding words. If the current word is position `i` then the word before it is at position `i - ...` ?

Comment: Please show the expected results for a given input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest slicing `words` depending on `i`:

```
print(words[i-5:i+6])
```

(This would go where your comment is)

Alternatively, to print as shown in your example:

```
print("...", " ".join(words[i-5:i+6]), "...")
```

To account for the word being in the first 5:

```
if i > 5:
    print("...", " ".join(words[i-5:i+6]), "...")
else:
    print("...", " ".join(words[0:i+6]), "...")
```

Additionally, `find` is not doing what you think it is. If `find()` doesn't find the string, it returns `-1` which evaluates to `True` when used in a if statement. Try:

```
if word in words[i].lower():
```

Comment: I tried that however this is the output and text file: https://imgur.com/a/5qdmK.

Comment: I believe I have fixed the issue @sam44

Answer (score 0):

This retrieves the index of every occurrence of the word in `words`, which is a list of all words in the file. Then slicing is used to get a list of the matched word and the 5 words before and after.

```
def occurs(word, filename):
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    infile.close()

    wordsString = ''.join(lines)
    words = wordsString.split()

    matches = [i for i, w in enumerate(words) if w.lower().find(word) != -1]

    for m in matches:
        l = " ".join(words[m-5:m+6])
        print(f"... {l} ...")
```

Comment: Maybe `if word in w.lower()`? To account for punctuation and capitalization.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts Good point. Should have used `find()` instead of checking equality as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [`more_itertools.adajacent`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.adjacent) tool.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


s = """\
But we did not answer him, for he was a stranger and we were not used to, strangers and were shy of them.
We were simple folk, in our village, and when a stranger was a pleasant person we were soon friends.
"""

word, distance = "stranger", 5
words = s.splitlines()[0].split()
```

**Demo**

```
neighbors = list(mit.adjacent(lambda x: x == word, words, distance))

" ".join(word for bool_, word in neighbors if bool_)
# 'him, for he was a stranger and we were not used'
```

---

**Details**

`more_itertools.adjacent` returns an iterable of tuples, e.g. (`bool`, item) pairs.  A `True` boolean is returned for words in the string that satisfy the predicate.  Example:

```
>>> neighbors
[(False, 'But'),
 ...
 (True, 'a'),
 (True, 'stranger'),
 (True, 'and'),
 ...
 (False, 'to,')]
```

Neighboring words are filtered from the results given a `distance` from the target word.

*Note:  [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library. Install by [`pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).*

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see rolling views of files, I think [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque)

```
import collections

def occurs(needle, fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    words = iter(''.join(lines).split())

    view = collections.deque(maxlen=11)
    # prime the deque
    for _ in range(10):  # leaves an 11-length deque with 10 elements
        view.append(next(words, ""))
    for w in words:
        view.append(w)
        if view[5] == needle:
            yield list(view.copy())
```

Note that this approach intentionally does not handle any edge cases for `needle` names in the first 5 words or the last 5 words of the file. The question is ambiguous as to whether matching the third word should give the first through ninth words, or something different.